# xfce4-power-manager closed when Battery is removed

Tags: lubuntu, 15.10, power-management, battery, xfce4-power-manager

I am Running Lubuntu 15.10. And I remove my Laptop battery during night times to prevent overcharging of my battery. And for some reason xfce4-power-manager is closed when i remove my battery(While the laptop is on). And the settings are ignored.
Is there any way to prevent this from happening or is the default power manager not xfce4-power-manager for lubuntu

Comment: `xfce4-power-manager` is Lubuntu's default power manager.

Comment: @DKBose Can i resolve this problem by installing a another power manager or is there some script to start `xfce4-power-manager` when battery is removed

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know about a script or about using a replacement for xfce4-power-manager. Why do you think your battery will overcharge?

Comment: @DKBose because i am pluging it for 7-9 hrs and i aldready had to replace my battery once because of it

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the battery icon turns off? In that case, change the power management settings to always show icon, from show icon only when battery is present.

Comment: No. I had swtich display off option for "When laptop lid is closed". But when i removed my battery it is locking the screen

Comment: No idea Mohit, maybe it needs an expert's opinion. Regards